# Unable to click on button in webpage using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to click on a button available in webpage.I have tried the below code 
and not know what should be added in the space where i have added xxxxxxxxxxx. Kindly assist me to solve this.below is the inspect element content of the button

```
<button class="aui-button aui-button-primary search-button" type="button" original-title="Search for issues" resolved="">Search</button>
```

Code that i have tried,

```
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

With ie.document
Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set HTMLButtons = htmldoc.getElementByTagName("button")

    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
          xxxxxx
    Next HTMLButton
    HTMLButtons(0).Click
   End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

The method `.getElementByTagName()` does not exist.

Instead the method you should use is `.getElementsByTagName()`, which does not return one single element, but a collection of elements.

To get the `i-th` element that belongs to the collection of elements whose tag name is "button" you would have to use this:

```
.getElementsByTagName("button")(i-1)
```